# Error in unique.default but I am not using unique!! R Shiny app build

Tags: r, shiny, visualization, unique

Hey Stacked overflow community,

Only built one Shiny app before but running into problems with this one! I keep getting this error which is preventing me from showing my treemap. Very confused because I seem to get this error even when I am not using the unique function.

**Error is**

Warning: The select input "importer" contains a large number of options; consider using server-side selectize for massively improved performance. See the Details section of the ?selectizeInput help topic.

Warning: The select input "year" contains a large number of options; consider using server-side selectize for massively improved performance. See the Details section of the ?selectizeInput help topic.

Warning: Error in unique.default: unique() applies only to vector

**Code so far...**

```
# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Use tags$head to include custom CSS styles
  tags$head( tags$title('2023 Pacific Data Visualisation entry'),
    tags$style(HTML("
      body {
        background-color: #c9e8fc;
        font-family: Arial;
      }
      h1 {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #032e9b;
      }
    "))
  ),
  titlePanel("PACIFIC DATA VISUALISATION"),
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    "Please pick the importer country(s) and year(s) you are interested in seeing information for", width = 4, 
    #selectizeInput("exporter", "Exporter:", choices = data_pv$exporter, multiple = TRUE),
    selectizeInput("importer", "Importer:", data_pv$importer, multiple = FALSE),
    selectizeInput("year", "Year:", data_pv$year, multiple = FALSE)
    #selectizeInput("commodity", "Commodity:", choices = unique(data_pv$commodity), multiple = TRUE)
    ),
  mainPanel( h4("Treemap of selected importer commodities"),
    plotlyOutput("treemap", width = "100%", height = "600px")
  )
)
)

# Define server logic for the Shiny app
server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  output$treemap <- renderPlotly({
    # Filter data based on selected year and importer
    filteredData <- data_pv %>%
      filter(year %in% input$year,
             importer %in% input$importer)
    
    # Filter out commodities with obs_val of 0
    filteredData <- filteredData %>%
      filter(obs_val > 0)
    
    labels <- filteredData$commodity
    parents <- ""
    values <- filteredData$obs_val
    color_palette <- scale_color_brewer(palette = "BrBG")
    
    treemap <- plot_ly(
      type='treemap',
      labels=labels,
      parents=parents,
      values = values,
      # textinfo="label+percent entry+percent root",
      #domain=list(column=0),
      color = color_palette)
    
    treemap
  })
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Trouble shooting

Using selectInput, selectiveInput

Creating a dynamic update in the server code - I ended up just trying to keep it simple as was getting the same error with this enter image description here

checked that data_pv is a data frame and not a vector
[Error codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVn16.png)
[data_pv structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37HEu.png)

Comment: Can you successfully create the treemap outside of the shiny app? Consider sharing `data_pv` or a sample to make your questions reproducible. This will increase your chances to get an answer. To do so, post the output of `dput(data_pv)` (full data) or `dput(head(data_pv), 10)` (first 10 rows) in a code chunk in your question,

Comment: These are warnings, not errors. Your `data_pv$importer` contains duplicates. I suspect other columns do too. But I can’t be sure because your question is not reproducible. I also suspect that `selectizeInput` is using `unique` internally as part of its initialisation. If you use `unique` explicitly yourself to remove duplicated `choices` I expect the warnings will disappear.